# Knockout JS: Is it good to access DOM directly by jquery when using Knockout JS

Tags: jquery, dom, knockout.js

some time ago some where i read a snip that people should not access or manipulate DOM when using knockout js. i just recently consulting a sample code from a popular blog http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet/876/change-tracking-data-binding-aspnet-knockoutjs

and i was they are accessing DOM from knockout js function. is it good or bad.

### some sample code

```
var viewModel =
{
…
editBlog: function (blog)
{
  $("#selectView").fadeOut("slow");
  $("#editView").fadeIn("slow");
},
updateBlog: function (blog)
{
  viewModel.commitSelected(blog);
  $("#editView").fadeOut("slow");
},
cancelEdit: function (blog)
{
  $("#editView").fadeOut("slow");
},
commitSelected: function (blog)
{
  for (var property in blog)
  {
   if (blog.hasOwnProperty(property) && blog[property].commit)
    blog[property].commit();
  }
},

newBlog: function ()
{
  this.blogs.push(toKoObservable({
   Title: "New " + this.blogs().length + 1,
   Id: this.blogs().length + 1,
   Post: "Post " + this.blogs().length,
   IsNew: true
  }));
}
}
```

i am looking for advise the above code is right practice or evil one which may cause problem. if the above code is not good then tell me what kind of problem may occur when some one access DOM from knockout view model function.

please guide me what will be the down side.

Comment: those DOM "manipulations" are just jquery-ui fanciness, they aren't really changing anything. what you shouldn't be doing is adding/removing/moving DOM elements around, because you're going to lose your bindings

Comment: so the above code is fine the way they are accessing DOM ?

Comment: yes, they're not really modifying anything, just adding classes/styles

Comment: how to dynamically add element or remove element from DOM when using knockout js. i am just looking for guide line which i like to follow.

Comment: i am bit curious to know that if i add or remove element in DOM by jquery when using ko.......then what will be the consequences. please discuss it with example code. thanks

Comment: you'd be adding/removing elements if you're looping over a collection. it's all in the documentation

Comment: i know there is doc but i like to know if i add/remove element by jquery then what bad consequences will occur when working with knockoutjs. can u plzz focus on this area......if possible discuss with sample code.

Comment: I told you, you'll lose your bindings if you're manipulating DOM elements that are under knockout's "control"

Comment: i understand what u try to say but like to see a similar code example which show me losing your ko bindings if try to add and remove element by jquery. will you please post a little sample code of such type . just a request......thanks

Comment: no, it's just like I said, I don't need to put together a code sample

Comment: @jeroen I don't know if your understanding or just your explanation of Code Review's requirements are wrong, but we have **very** different requirements from SO. (working? yes. Minimal? No. Also, example, hypothetical or stub code is automatically Off-Topic anyway.) you (and the O.P.) should check out [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's bad.

By using functions like `cancelEdit`, you're creating an application state that is no longer fully embodied by your knockout model. Is the editor open or shut? By poking the UI with jQuery, we just lost track of that information, so we've dispersed application state to places where we can no longer keep track of them. We have to use more jQuery to query the state of the UI. Let this rot continue, and very soon, what was a nice, manageable knockout application no longer behaves very nicely because making the UI change can't be done predictably from knockout.

Keeping a part of your application's state implicitly in the state of the UI is a bad thing, and that's exactly what poking the DOM with jQuery forces you to do.

Far more idiomatic is to have a UI that depends on the state of the model:

```
<div data-bind="visible:$data.editorIsVisible">
    <!-- editor stuff -->
</div>
```

now the method `cancelEdit` could:

```
var editorIsVisible = ko.observable(true); //this would be somewhere in the bound model
function cancelEdit(){
    editorIsVisible(false); //good, update the model, UI follows automatically
}
```

If (for instance) the "abruptness" of the `visible` binding tempts you into using jQuery, then this should be carefully managed by used of a new type of bindingHandler. See http://knockoutjs.com/examples/animatedTransitions.html for examples.

In short, my *personal opinion* is that jquery should not be used to heavily in conjunction with knockout, and when it is absolutely necessary, it should be used in a way that plays nicely with the knockout model, not to make the UI do something "over knockout's head".

Since I adopted the knockout way, I find that jQuery really takes a back seat.